Sharing/Accessing values across two yaml files - Spring Boot Config
Is it possible to share or access a value across two yml files in the same project (Spring Boot Config).
I do have an application.yml file which looks as usual, but it contains common configurations which can be (re)used by all my other Microservices (Clients).
I'm interested in using the value I've set for my datasources in my other yml file location-service.yml
For an example:
# Spring Security & Common Configurations
    security:
        user:
            name: ${EMP_CONFIG_USERNAME}
            password: ${EMP_CONFIG_PASSWORD}
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://${DB_HOST}:${DB_PORT}/
        username: ${DB_USER}
        password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
        driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

And in my location-service.yml I want to do something like this (pseudo code):
# Datasource - MySQL
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${spring.datasource.url}${EMP_SCHEMA_LOCATION}
    username: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password}
    driver-class-name: ${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}

But is looks like it's not working. My GitHub action build pipeline "build-dev.yml" should replace the values which are written with the placeholder "$" symbol. And since I've already uploaded my dev.env into GitHub secrets it should work. Unfortunately the result looks remotely like this:
# Datasource - MySQL
spring:
  datasource:
    url: ${spring.datasource.url}location_db
    username: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password}
    driver-class-name: ${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}

  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    show-sql: true

  test:
    database:
      replace: ${spring.test.database.replace}

Any professional who knows where my error is?
Thank you very much in advance!
